# Python Printing in Terminal

Tags: python, printing

I am sorry to post what I think may be a very basic question, but my attempts at solving this have been futile, and I can't find a useful solution that has already been suggested to similar questions on this site.

My basic issue is this: I am attempting to run a file (coding UTF-8) as a program in Mac terminal (running Python 2.7.5). This works fine when I print the results of a mathematical operations, but for some reason I cannot print a simple string of characters.

I have tried running both:

```
# coding: utf-8
print "Hello, World."
exit()
```

and

```
# coding: utf-8
print("Hello, World.")
exit()
```

Both return an invalid syntax error, with the caret pointing at first set of quotation marks that I've used. What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this part of a file or an interpreter session? Check for previous code for a missing closing double quotes or parenthesis.

Comment: Can you post the output of `python -V` when run through `bash`?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! It turned out that I needed to disable smart quotes in TextEdit. Ugh.

Comment: @user3399476 There you go :)

Comment: @user3399476 Post this as an answer and accept it yourself (or just delete the question) since it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I needed to disable smart quotes in TextEdit.